# Calculate time in Excel

Tags: excel

i have two columns in xl sheet A row have this format "8:25 PM EDT" and B row have this format "10:12:15 AM" , Now i want to add one hour to the B column if the A column contains the text "EDT" , Please help me to find out the solution 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to accept an answer if that solved your problem. Or post a comment saying why that is not the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

edited: IFERROR(IF(FIND("EDT",A1)>0,B1+TIME(1,0,0)),A1)

Comment: But i got the answer as #value ?

Comment: Your 10:12 is probably text.  Try

IFERROR(IF(FIND("EDT",A1)>0,TIMEVALUE(B1)+TIME(1,0,0)),A1)